# How does X509Certificate2Collection.Find define a valid certificate

Tags: .net, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I ran into a problem recently and was hoping someone could provide some insight.  A certificate was expiring so we replaced it.  There was a period where both the old and the new certificate was valid.  When the old certificate expired, the following code still returned both the new and the expired certificate:

```
X509Certificate2Collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true)
```

By what criteria does .Net consider a certificate valid.  Does .Net consider a certificate valid until midnight UTC (like it should) or midnight local time.

In the end, we simply removed the old certificate and everything was fine; but I don't want the same problem next time we need to replace a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

First, `X509Certificate2Collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true)` method executes `X509Certificate2.Verify()` method on each object in the collection to determine whether the certificate is valid. `Verify()` method performs a lot of checks (in accordance with RFC 5280).

Regarding validity. Validity in the certificate (internally) is stored in UTC format and .NET converts this UTC time to local time. When you open the certificate and see that it is valid until midnight, then the certificate is valid until midnight in your current time zone (not UTC midnight).